# Esquema MVC en PHP

Tags: php, mvc, crud

Tengo una pregunta sencilla (pero para mí muy complicada de resolver) sobre desarrollo MVC en PHP.

Pretendo desarrollar un CRUD en PHP siguiendo MVC. He creado mis carpetas para el Modelo, la Vista y el Controlador, y he creado mi `index.php` que llama a cada uno de los controladores del CRUD. Hasta ahí todo perfecto, sin problema.

El problema viene cuando desde la vista de inserción de datos recojo por formulario los datos que quiero guardar en la bbdd con el método POST. Ahí va la pregunta...

Cuando los recojo dónde debo enviarlos, al controlador o al modelo. Porque los estoy enviando al controlador y guardándolos en una variable, y luego el modelo no reconoce la variable

Dejo ejemplo...

ARCHIVO MODELO

```
<?php

    class Usuarios{

        private $db;
        private $nombre;


        public function __construct(){

            require_once "/models/conexion.php";
            require_once "/controllers/usuarios_controllers.php";

            $this->db = Conexion::conectar();
            $this->nombre = $nombre; //ESTA ES LA VARIABLE QUE NO ME RECONOCE

        }

        public function insertarUsuario(){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre) VALUES ($this->nombre)";

            $consulta = $this->db->query($sql);

        }

    }

?>
```

ARCHIVO CONTROLADOR

```
<?php

    require_once "models/usuarios_models.php";

    if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){

        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; //ESTA ES LA VARIABLE QUE NO LOGRO PASAR AL MODELO

        $crearUsuario = new Usuarios();
        $crearUsuario->insertarUsuario();

    }

    require_once "views/usuarios_views.php";

?>
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: no te reconoce la variable en el modelo porque 1) no lo pasas desde el controlador en el new(o con otro metodo) y 2) no lo recojes en tu modelo.

Comment: Podrías ponerme ejemplo de código por favor, no entiendo exactamente cómo se hace.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu modelo deberías recoger los datos que necesitas, desde el metodo constructor. Tu metodo deberia ser algo como:

```
    public function __construct($nombre){
        $this-nombre = $hombre;
        ....
```

asimismo, en el controller, una vez que has recogido los datos con el $_POST, creas el modelo pasandole el dato:

```
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; 
    $crearUsuario = new Usuarios($nombre);
```

Entiendo que esto es un ejercicio mas bien académico. Te faltarían muchas cosas para verificar (Temas de inyección de dependencias, modelar repository en lugar de poner en el modelo la consulta, clases de modelos en singular, proteccion contra inyección sql...)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, no estaba cayendo en pasar el dato por parámetro. Mil gracias.

Sí, efectivamente es un ejercicio académico, no se detiene en la seguridad del proceso.